# Автоматическое разбиение одного видео на много маленьких частей (пазлов)

Tags: flash, php, html

Можно ли сделать чтобы видео например формат avi или wmv показывалось на сайте как на большом экране? Тоесть как будто состоит из маленьких экранов а в сумме с каждого из них получается одно изображение.

Если хоть как-то можно, скажите пожалуйста как :)

Comment: - AVI, WMV флеш не воспроизводит, нужно конвертить в FLV/F4V формат
 - Не совсем понятна задача: нужно много потоков играть на сайте как одно большое или один поток воспроизводить с разных мест в нескольких проигрывателях
 - зачем разбивать на несколько экранов/потоков? чем не подходит FullHD(1920px)? флеш прекрасно воспроизводит и 4К разрешение (на ютубе есть примеры) на приличной машине (i5-2500/Geforce560)

Comment: Имеется ввиду, что бы видео на сайте автоматически показывалось так: http://www.combonews.ru/uploads/posts/2009-09/1253099895_ati-eyefinity-wow.jpg

Comment: *trollface*
<table border="20px" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1000; width: 100%; height: 100%" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Поверх одного видео положить рамки с маской (прозрачностью), которые будут имитировать разделение на экраны.
- Если каждое видео нужно сдвигать на ширину полоски рамки, тогда надо создавать несколько плееров со своими масками (classes [Video](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Video.html), [Mask](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#mask)).
- Само видео можно отредактировать с наложением рамок (Adobe Premiere, Adobe AFX, Nuke), правда при изменении рамки придется перекодировать всё заново.

Comment: А автоматом разделять подобным образом со сдвигом на ширину рамки не получиться?

Comment: Да не вопрос: пишите цикл, с созданием видео плееров, в нем задаете сдвиг и ширину/высоту каждого.

Comment: На чем пишем? На флэше это делать?

Comment: ActionScript 3
FlashBuilder например - https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash_builder